# GCP assign one user the access of only one instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I am trying to grant access to my compute engine VM to one of my colleagues. For that I am using this answer: 
[GCP answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52756755/how-to-give-access-to-single-compute-instance-on-gcp)

Here I gave him access according to the answer. But I want him to access the VM with different uses for example:

I created a VM and installed my Django application under my email: abc@abc.com and it created a user called abc@abc.com. and my Django is there.

But when I am granting access to my partner's email: abc1@abc.com he is logging to the VM with his user and he can't access my Django folder because he is accessing it with his user.

So my question is how can I assign abc1@abc.com to log in as an abc1@abc.com. This is frustrating in AWS you give a .pem file and anyone can access. Do GCP have that kind of trick. And if not how can I achieve this.

Comment: If you want to use one user ID to log into the instance, you need to use an SSH key pair and then specify the user name when connecting via an SSH command line tool or GUI. If you are using the Google Cloud Console GUI, then the logged in identity is used. - Yes, Google uses the same type of SSH key pairs (pem) as AWS.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely because you're installing your Django folder inside your own users home directory. Other users won't have access to it. 
What you can do to share files across users is put the files under a folder in the root directory (/).
You could also give him permissions to access that folder by adding him to the authorized group. https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions